# Angular Materials autocomplete doesn't close

Tags: angular, angular-material-6

When you're looking to the official example, the autocomplete list closes when the focus gets lost using Tab: 
[Angular Material Autocomplete documentation/example](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview)

In my implementation, the popup stays open when 'tabbing' out of the control. It only closes when I click with the mouse somewhere else, or if I choose a proposed element. What am I doing wrong that it doesn't behave like the orginal element? I have the newest Material version, and it is the same if I use FormControls instead of [(ngModel)]...

```
    <mat-form-field>
      <input matInput 
          type="text"
          placeholder="Market Name" 
          [(ngModel)]="marketname" 
          [matAutocomplete]="auto">
      <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" class="autocomplete">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let m of marketnames" [value]="m" class="option">{{m}}</mat-option>
      </mat-autocomplete>
    </mat-form-field>
```

Comment: You can use (optionSelected) in mat-autocomplete. It will close the mat-component

Comment: You mean the EventEmitter, right? I tried to call its emit() and also showPanel=false (on blur of the input field). But it has no effect, the popup stays open.